# Google Cloud Composer failed after restart

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer, gke-networking

I have Google cloud composer running in 2 GCP projects. I have updated composer environment variable in both. One composer restarted fine within few minutes. I have problem in another & it shows below error as shown in images.

**Update operation failed. Couldn't start composer-agent, a GKE job that updates kubernetes resources. Please check if your GKE cluster exists and is healthy.**

[This is the error what I see when I enter the composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMytz.png)

[This is the environment overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYTJP.png)

[GKE cluster notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMWSq.png)

[GKE pods overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDyes.png)

I am trying to find how to resolve the problem but I didn't find any satisfied answers. My colleagues are assuming firewall & org policies issue but I haven't changed any.

Can some one let me know what caused this problem as the google composer is managed by google & how to resolve this issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Once the Cloud Composer is the managed resource and when the GKE which serves the environment for your composer is unhealthy you should try to contact Google Cloud Support. That GKE should work just fine and you do not need even know about its existence.

Also check whether you do not reacy any limits or quotas in your project.

When nothing helps recreation of Cloud Composer is always good idea.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was someone deleted proxying Load balancer for managed GKE. But now its solved